# How to make UI in PhoneGap, jQuery Mobile good?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm new to PhoneGap. I created a sample application using ponegap and jquery mobile which contain some button and few other form elements. While I installed in my mobile(Samsung Ace), i feel the UI of button and few other form elements are not looking good. Cornering in button is not perfect[image: Screen Shot].
I'm using the following

1. cordova-2.9.0.jar
2. jquery-2.0.3.min.js
3. jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js
4. jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css

   Am i missing anything? Please help me.How to make the UI look and feel good?

Thanks

Comment: try running the official site of jquerymobile in your device, that will also render the buttons in similar fashion, nothing can be done much...you need to go for other UI framework...

Comment: Idk about you, but jquerymobile.com is down for me atm..

Answer (score 2):

To make UI in Phonegap, jQuery Mobile is good, but not the best. If You want the best result in performance and UI then you'll have to use [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/). Please visit this [Link](http://www.gajotres.net/sencha-touch-vs-jquery-mobile/) it may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `ThemeRoller` to get your UI in `jQuerymobile` framework

Check the following link

http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/index.php

Answer (score 1):

Speaking for myself, I've used jQuery Mobile with Phonegap, and I'm fairly happy with it. I don't think the problem you're having with the corners is jquery mobile, but rather related to whatever emulator program you're using; they work fine for me on various resolutions on my laptop, tablet, s3 & iphone, even when I zoom out/in between 25% and 500% on chrome using [ripple](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc).

To make a nicer interface, you can use jQuery Mobile's [ThemeRoller](http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/index.php).

Comment: I have tried in mobile also. Same format its get shown. And for list views on right side of each row there right arrow icon will be there. But for its showing only grey circle, arrow is not getting shown.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile framework is not important for phonegap app, you can customize your own styles using normal HTML and CSS (CSS3 also).